# SciTE text editor, anyone know how to find documentation for advanced techniques?

Tags: ruby, editor, scintilla, scite

I have chosen to use SciTE as my text editor. I know its a powerful editor and I have seen videos online where people are using advanced techniques with it. I really want to know how to use the editor as a power user. Anyone know how to lean advanced configurations with the editor so I can get the most out of my coding?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly what you mean by advanced configurations, maybe you can be more specific?

However, these might be good places to start:

- [SciTE Documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html)
- [SciTE extensions Documentation](http://scitedebug.luaforge.net/)